# Why is it not possible to group Telerik chart legend items?

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik, kendo-chart, kendo-ui-mvc

I would need to group the elements of a Kendochart series, so they are separated as follows:

**Group Title 1**: 

Serie 1. 

Serie 2. 

**Group Title 2**: 

Serie 3. 

Serie 4.

I tried it with a template, but it does not work.

```
legend: {
    labels: {
        template: kendo.template($("legend-template").html())
    }
}, 

<script id="legend-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div id="Leyenda">  #: text # </div>
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: The solution was to create a new div with a checkbox for each of the series and through jQuery to play with the checked property of these, alternating the visualization of each elements of the series.

For Example:

```
 $("#SerieName").change(function () {
            if ($("#SerieName").is(":checked")) {
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[0].visible = true;
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();

            } else {

                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[0].visible = false;
                $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
            }
        });
```